# How to use like condition in Conditional Split in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, conditional-formatting

I am using conditional split to filter out the data from table. I have couple of conditions to check for. For example, In Email column, value should not contain ~ character and contain @ sign. Date of birth column, year should not be greater than current year, month should not be greater that 12 and day should not be greater than 31.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE Email LIKE '%~%'
   OR NOT (Email LIKE "%@%")
   OR SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DOb, 23), 1, 2) <= 12
   OR SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DOb, 23), 4, 2) <= 31
   OR SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DOb, 23), 7, 4) <= YEAR(GETDATE());
```

I have above sql query for the same. But not sure how to implement it in SSIS using conditional split.

Comment: Why are you converting your `DOb` column to a `varchar` and then implicitly converting the value to an `int`? Why are you not using a date boundary?

Comment: Also `Email LIKE "%~%"` is likely to give the error *"Invalid column name '%~%'"*. Double quotes are the ansi-SQL delimit identifier for **object** names; single quotes (`'`) are for literal strings.

Comment: Also, see [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @Larnu email like condition is updated in question. It was a typo. Any idea how to perform like in conditional split in SSIS please.

Comment: Considering that you are simply looking for a single character, you could use `FINDSTRING`, which *"Returns the location of the specified occurrence of a string within a character expression. The string parameter must evaluate to a character expression, and the occurrence parameter must evaluate to an integer."*. (SSIS's equivalent of `CHARINDEX`.)

Comment: @Larnu FINDSTRING will return me character index. I want to get that full row in which email column has ~ value.

Comment: Correct, that is exactly what it does, and therefore you know if the character is (or isn't) in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional columns in your source query depending on your conditions and then use those columns in conditional split .

```
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN Email LIKE '%@%'
                OR Email LIKE '%~%'
                THEN 'bad data'
            ELSE 'good data'
            END AS emaildatatype
        ,*
    FROM [table]
WHERE Email LIKE '%~%'
        OR NOT (Email LIKE "%@%")
        OR SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DOb, 23), 1, 2) <= 12
        OR SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DOb, 23), 4, 2) <= 31
        OR SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DOb, 23), 7, 4) <= YEAR(GETDATE());
```

Comment: where should I add above query in my flow.

Comment: are you using directly table as source or sql command? if you are using sql command in source then you can modify that